# Android listview stack items like in Android L recent apps

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, listview, carousel

I want to create a listview like the new Android L recent apps listview. I have allready tried stackview which doesn't have a clear scrolling feeling and I find it hard to change that. I also tried the [Andrdoid carousel layout](https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/) library but again that does not act as a scrollview nor a listview so it doesn't really help me. Do you know any libraries or and points from where to start from?

[image]

Comment: possibly you could set the top margin negatively when the user scrolls down. Then of course each of your items would been a shadow

Comment: Hi, Sorry I haven't something to be stable and fast enough